# Mysql Data truncation for Valid DECIMAL

Tags: mysql, decimal

```
create table test(id INT, value DECIMAL(25,6));
insert into test values (16, 10e16);
insert into test values (17, 10e17);  -- Works till here
insert into test values (18, 10e18);  -- Fails here. Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'value'
insert into test values (19, 10e19);
```

How is this possible?

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I should be able to insert values till 10e25 right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DECIMAL(25,6) stores 25 digits, 6 of them fractional, i.e. a value up to `9,999,999,999,999,999,999.999999`

`10e18` is `10,000,000,000,000,000,000.000000`

Answer (score 1):

What is `DECIMAL(25,6)` ?

- 19 digits to the left of the decimal
- 06 digits to the right of the decimal

**`10e18` is not a 19-digit number. It's a 20-digit number**

```
mysql> select 10e18 ActualValue;
+-------------+
| ActualValue |
+-------------+
|        1e19 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

That's 1 with 19 zeros.

Therefore, a 20-digit number will not fit inside the 19 digits imposed by `DECIMAL(25,6)`